# Getting the latest 5 unique entries

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I have an Access database that I am interacting with using JET with the following structure:

```
ID  UsersID
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   1
```

What I am trying to do is get the latest unique entries. eg:

```
ID  UsersID
5   1
4   3
3   2
```

However, I am having trouble mixing grouping and ordering. I have tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT [UsersID] FROM [Table] ORDER BY [ID] DESC
SELECT [UsersID] FROM [Table] GROUP BY [UsersID] ORDER BY [ID] DESC
```

But, no luck. Note: if I leave off the `ORDER BY [ID] DESC` from either query, it works, but obviously the ordering is not as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the largest ID value for each UserID with a simple GROUP BY query.

```
SELECT UserID, Max(ID) AS MaxOfID
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY UserID;
```

However I'm not sure I understand the order by and latest 5 requirements.  If latest 5 means the 5 largest ID values from the above query, then try it this way ...

```
SELECT TOP 5 UserID, Max(ID) AS MaxOfID
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY UserID
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

"Table" is not the best name for a table.  Hope your real world situation uses a different table name.  :-)

Comment: No, "Table" is not the real name. Interesting, if I do `ORDER BY [ID] DESC` I get an error, but if I do `ORDER BY 1 DESC` everything is great

Comment: Not sure which query you're talking about.  If it's a GROUP BY which includes Max(ID), you can use Max(ID) in the ORDER BY instead of using the field expression's ordinal position.

Comment: What I meant is, I can't combine `GROUP BY` and `ORBER BY` and use any field in the table without getting an error, but I can use the ordinal position like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5  ID, UserID FROM 
table 
where UserID in (SELECT DISTINCT UserID from table ORDER BY ID DESC)
```